# Resize UICollectionViewCell to fit image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, resize, uicollectionviewcell

I'd like to resize UICollectionViewCell to fit image that is sensibly resized and maintains dimensions/aspect ratio. If I simply set the size of cell to size of image it may be way too big. Also, If I run on different sized devices, the spacing isn't consistent. Must I implement collectionView programmatically to overcome this?

I see many apps that do this so its a very common problem that may already be solved as a framework.

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UICollectionView is actually of arbitrary layout.  It so happens that the default is UICollectionViewFlowLayout which is a grid, but you can change it to anything by implmenting your own instance of the [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout) protocol.  Int the case you cited its pretty easy.  The width of the cells is the collectionview (width minus the padding) divided by two.  The height is the aspect ratio times the width + the spacing + the label height.  all the cells with indices divisible by 2 go in the right column and the rest go in the left column.  It should be easy to calculate these values for [layoutAttributesForItem(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelements).  Unfortunately its a bit harder to calculate for [collectionViewContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize).  Assuming your collectionview is sufficiently small I think its best to just precalculate all of the hieghts and use the cached values for these functions.

Answer (score -1):

There're a lot of open sources on github You can refer to.

https://github.com/zhangsuya/SYStickHeaderWaterFall

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Xcoder why do you say that? I've been a member longer than you.

Comment: @AnonProgrammer  not telling to you keep calm , He is telling to  

成文权  who has just posted URL as answer which should be a comment  !!